# Is it possible to create a new column in a dataframe that is the output of a function using mutate in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I need to run a self-made function across rows and create an output column in the same data frame (column name `tt_daily`). This is some made up example.

```
#data
data1 <- read.csv(text = "
doy,tmx,tmn,relHum,srad
148,31.3,13.8,68.3,30.4
149,31.1,17.2,62.2,30
150,30.1,16.1,69.7,20.9
151,27.3,16.2,77.1,26.1
152,33.4,18.4,65.9,27.4
153,27.2,18,70.3,26.6
154,30.3,13,71.5,28.4
155,36.2,22,62.2,28.8
156,32.9,22.2,61.1,24.9
157,30.5,16.2,63.2,27.9
158,25.7,19.3,71,18.3
159,29.1,18.3,87.2,12.7
160,28.5,20.3,70.2,24.8
")
```

This is the function:

```
# function to run row wise
tb<- 11
topt<- 30
tmax<- 42

tt<-function(tmx, tmn, tb, topt, tmax){
  
  tmean<- (tmx + tmn) / 2
  
  if(tmean <= tb) {t1 = 0}
  if(tmean >tb & tmean <=topt) {t1 = tmean - tb}
  if(tmean>topt & tmean<max) {t1 = (topt - tb) / (topt - tmax) * (tmean - tmax)}
  if(tmean >= tmax) {t1 <- 0}
  return(t1)
  
}
```

This is two options of what I did:

```
#Option 1
library(dplyr)

tt.example <- data1 %>%
  mutate(tt_daily = purrr::pmap(function(tmx, tmn, tb, topt, tmax) tt))
```

and this is the error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `tt_daily`.
> i `tt_daily = purrr::pmap(function(tmx, tmn, tb, topt, tmax) tt)`.
> x argument ".f" is missing, with no default

This is the option 2:

```
#Option 2
tt.example <- data1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(tt_daily = tt(tmx, tmn, tb, topt, tmax))
```

This is the error I got:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `tt_daily`.
> i `tt_daily = tt(tmx, tmn, tb, topt, tmax)`.
> x comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types
> i The error occurred in row 1.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: @akrun,   No, they are set as objects outside the dataset. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the function which should be `tmax` instead of `max`

```
tt<-function(tmx, tmn, tb, topt, tmax){
  
  tmean<- (tmx + tmn) / 2
  
  
  if(tmean <= tb) {t1 = 0}
  if(tmean >tb & tmean <=topt) {t1 = tmean - tb}
  if(tmean>topt & tmean<tmax) {t1 = (topt - tb) / (topt - tmax) * (tmean - tmax)}
  if(tmean >= tmax) {t1 <- 0}
  return(t1)
  
}
```

Now, we apply the function within `mutate` after appending the other arguments as a named `list` within `pmap`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data1 %>% 
    mutate(tt_daily = pmap_dbl(c(across(tmx:tmn), 
             dplyr::lst(tb, topt, tmax)), tt))
```

-output

```
doy  tmx  tmn relHum srad tt_daily
1  148 31.3 13.8   68.3 30.4    11.55
2  149 31.1 17.2   62.2 30.0    13.15
3  150 30.1 16.1   69.7 20.9    12.10
4  151 27.3 16.2   77.1 26.1    10.75
5  152 33.4 18.4   65.9 27.4    14.90
6  153 27.2 18.0   70.3 26.6    11.60
7  154 30.3 13.0   71.5 28.4    10.65
8  155 36.2 22.0   62.2 28.8    18.10
9  156 32.9 22.2   61.1 24.9    16.55
10 157 30.5 16.2   63.2 27.9    12.35
11 158 25.7 19.3   71.0 18.3    11.50
12 159 29.1 18.3   87.2 12.7    12.70
13 160 28.5 20.3   70.2 24.8    13.40
```

---

Or using `rowwise`

```
data1 %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(tt_daily = tt(tmx, tmn, tb, topt, tmax)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 6
     doy   tmx   tmn relHum  srad tt_daily
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1   148  31.3  13.8   68.3  30.4     11.6
 2   149  31.1  17.2   62.2  30       13.2
 3   150  30.1  16.1   69.7  20.9     12.1
 4   151  27.3  16.2   77.1  26.1     10.8
 5   152  33.4  18.4   65.9  27.4     14.9
 6   153  27.2  18     70.3  26.6     11.6
 7   154  30.3  13     71.5  28.4     10.6
 8   155  36.2  22     62.2  28.8     18.1
 9   156  32.9  22.2   61.1  24.9     16.5
10   157  30.5  16.2   63.2  27.9     12.4
11   158  25.7  19.3   71    18.3     11.5
12   159  29.1  18.3   87.2  12.7     12.7
13   160  28.5  20.3   70.2  24.8     13.4
```

---

If we want to add a new column, then it may be better to either return a `list` or `tibble` in 'tt' function

```
tt<-function(tmx, tmn, tb, topt, tmax){
   
   tmean<- (tmx + tmn) / 2
   
   
   if(tmean <= tb) {t1 = 0}
   if(tmean >tb & tmean <=topt) {t1 = tmean - tb}
   if(tmean>topt & tmean<tmax) {t1 = (topt - tb) / (topt - tmax) * (tmean - tmax)}
   if(tmean >= tmax) {t1 <- 0}
   return(tibble(tt_daily = t1, tmean = tmean))
   
 }
```

Now, we wrap the contents in a `list` and `unnest` the output column

```
library(tidyr)
data1 %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(out = list(tt(tmx, tmn, tb, topt, tmax))) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    unnest_wider(c(out))
# A tibble: 13 x 7
     doy   tmx   tmn relHum  srad tt_daily tmean
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1   148  31.3  13.8   68.3  30.4     11.6  22.6
 2   149  31.1  17.2   62.2  30       13.2  24.2
 3   150  30.1  16.1   69.7  20.9     12.1  23.1
 4   151  27.3  16.2   77.1  26.1     10.8  21.8
 5   152  33.4  18.4   65.9  27.4     14.9  25.9
 6   153  27.2  18     70.3  26.6     11.6  22.6
 7   154  30.3  13     71.5  28.4     10.6  21.6
 8   155  36.2  22     62.2  28.8     18.1  29.1
 9   156  32.9  22.2   61.1  24.9     16.5  27.6
10   157  30.5  16.2   63.2  27.9     12.4  23.4
11   158  25.7  19.3   71    18.3     11.5  22.5
12   159  29.1  18.3   87.2  12.7     12.7  23.7
13   160  28.5  20.3   70.2  24.8     13.4  24.4
```

Comment: is there any way I can add a column with the ```tmean``` values using the ```rowwise``` approximation? From what I read, the functions provide only one output. But I am wondering whether there is way to somehow add a column with that intermediate object. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: @GiuseppePetri I think you can return a `tibble` in the function Please check the updated solution

Comment: This is awesome. Works great.